# stringstream::in syntax error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stringstream

I am trying to use a `stringstream` to do something like this (I simplified my code to pinpoint the error):

**Token.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Token {
public:
   static stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
   static void set_input_string(std::string str);
};
```

**Token.cpp**

```
#include "Token.h"

void Token::set_input_string(std::string str)
{
   ss << str;
}
```

When I try to compile i get:
`error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'in'` in Token.h on line `static stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);` and visual studios 2010 underlines in red `stringstream::in |`

Comment: Does the class really represent a token, or does it **produce** tokens by cutting up the input string? If it's the latter, you should (a) fix up class names to reflect that, and (b) not use a `static` member. If it really represents a token, then you should set its value in the constructor, and pass the stringstream to the constructor (let it do the work there to extract data from the stream).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot initialize non-integral values in the class definition. You should have:

```
// Token.h
#include <cstdio> // thisis the C++ header
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

// don't do this, especially not in a header file - function-scope at best
// using namespace std;

class Token {
public:
    static std::stringstream ss; // declare

    // probably want this parameter to be a const-reference
    static void set_input_string(std::string str);
};
```

And:

```
// Token.cpp
#include "Token.h"

// define
std::stringstream Token::ss(std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out); 

void Token::set_input_string(std::string str)
{
   ss << str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare and define a member variable at the same time. The definition of ss should be outside of the class declaration:

```
class Token {
public:
   static stringstream ss; // declaration
   static void set_input_string(std::string str);
};

stringstream Token::ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out); // definition in your cpp file
```